# Unable to instantiate the chaincode while running in docker swarm

Tags: docker-swarm, hyperledger-fabric

On instantiating the installed chaincode in Hyperldeger fabric network, setup in docker swarm, following error occurs:

> Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Timeout expired while starting chaincode 
>   mycc:1.0(networkid:fabricnetwork,peerid:peer0,tx:778dacf55114a5a26c6602f8fe7e3f326cdef8afbd897f4e5bacdd522033c08a)